# Python on appengine: error with eval()

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, eval, repr

I'm using App Engine's  webapp. This request handler outputs a form with a text field. On submission, it will get the text and add `<h1>` tags to lines that start with `#`. I used `repr()` to be able to split the text into a list of lines, and `eval()` to analyze the text from each line without the `u'` at the start of the string that comes from `repr()`.

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<form method=\'post\' action=\'\'>')
        self.response.out.write('<textarea name=\'text\'></textarea>')
        self.response.out.write('<input type=\'submit\' value=\'Submit\'/>')
        self.response.out.write('</form>')
    def post(self):
        output = []
        for line in repr(self.request.get('text')).split('\\n'):
            if eval(line)[0] == '#':
                output.append('<h1>'+line+'</h1>')
            else:
                output.append(line)
        self.response.out.write('\\n'.join(output))
```

The way the code is now, its giving me this error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    u'#somestring\r
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

If I use just `line[0]` instead of `eval(line)[0]`, everything works fine except that it doesn't work for the first line. Even if the first line starts with `#`, the conditional will go for the `else` because the first characters will be `u'` and not `#`. Trying to work around that with `eval()` is giving me that error. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: If I read this right, you are using `eval()` on input received from a web form?  This is a security problem waiting to happen.  `eval` actually executes the string as Python code.

Comment: Yeah now I realize that was a bad idea. I just didn't knew about `splitlines()`, so that was the only way I could think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To split the text, the strings have a built in `splitlines` method:

```
for line in self.request.get('text').splitlines():
    ... do whatever ...
```

Then to see if a particular line begins with a `#`, try this:

```
if line.strip()[0]=='#':
    ... do whatever ...
```

Put together:

```
for line in self.request.get('text').splitlines():
    if line.strip()[0] == '#':
        ... do whatever ...
```